# Terminal Error With Cocoapods

Tags: git, terminal, cocoapods

I git cloned a github project and then when I ran pod install it had an error with fetching some files or something. How to fix this?

Here is the Terminal Code.

```
Lucs-iMac:twiliochat-swift lucmollard$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.6 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `TwilioCommon` from     `https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/common/v0.2/TwilioCommon.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `TwilioIPMessagingClient` from `https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/rtc/ios/ip-messaging/v0.13/TwilioIPMessagingClient.podspec`
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `TwilioCommon (from `https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/common/v0.2/TwilioCommon.podspec`)` required by `Podfile`
- `TwilioCommon (= 0.2.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `twiliochat.xcworkspace` and `Podfile.lock` before you do `pod install`. 
Or you can just run `pod update`.